# PyQt5: Pass a value into QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5

how do you pass a value into  a QWidget in PyQt5?
Let's say everytime the user runs the GUI, the widget shows today's date for example.

Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from datetime import date

app = QApplication(['Show Date'])
today = date.today()
window = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'This QLabel shows the actual date: {today}')
window.show()
app.exec()
```